# How can i make the Contact email equals to the custom settings field? [TRIGGER]

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

### Trigger

### How can i make the Contact email equals to the custom settings field?

```
trigger CreateAccountContact on Account (after insert) {
List<Contact> ct = new List <Contact>();
for(Account acc : trigger.new){

    Contact a = new Contact(LastName ='Dela cruz',
                AccountId=acc.id,
                Fax=acc.Fax,
                Email= '',
                MailingStreet=acc.BillingStreet,
                MailingCity=acc.BillingCity,
                /* similarly add all fields which you want */
                MailingState=acc.BillingState,
                MailingPostalCode=acc.BillingPostalCode,
                MailingCountry=acc.BillingCountry,
                Phone=acc.Phone);

    ct.add(a);
    Contact b = new Contact(LastName = 'Arsola',
                AccountId=acc.id,
                Fax=acc.Fax,
                Email= '',
                MailingStreet=acc.BillingStreet,
                MailingCity=acc.BillingCity,
                /* similarly add all fields which you want */
                MailingState=acc.BillingState,
                MailingPostalCode=acc.BillingPostalCode,
                MailingCountry=acc.BillingCountry,
                Phone=acc.Phone);

    ct.add(b);
    Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Enanoria',
                AccountId=acc.id,
                Fax=acc.Fax,
                Email= '',
                MailingStreet=acc.BillingStreet,
                MailingCity=acc.BillingCity,
                /* similarly add all fields which you want */
                MailingState=acc.BillingState,
                MailingPostalCode=acc.BillingPostalCode,
                MailingCountry=acc.BillingCountry,
                Phone=acc.Phone);

    ct.add(c);
}
insert ct; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of Custom Setting you have (List or Hierarchy )

Say if its Hierarchy, you can use to get the default email value for your org

```
Email = YourCustomSettingName__c.getOrgDefaults().Email__c;
```

or if its a List Setting, you can use `getAll()` or `getValues()` methods

You can refer this [Salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_accessing.htm&language=en_US) for how to access custom setting in your Apex code

[another reference](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_customsettings.htm)

**Note :**

you don't need to do this inside the loop. get the value once into a variable at the beginning and use the variable.

also, you can move the contact initialisation code into a separate method and have the Last Name as a method parameter, so that you don't need to repeat the same code 3 times. you can simply call the method passing the different names.